# How to access a require'd controller from another controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have an Angular 1.3 module that looks something like this (directive that requires the presence of a parent directive, using `controllerAs`):

```
angular.module('fooModule', [])

.controller('FooController', function ($scope) {
  this.doSomething = function () {
    // Accessing parentDirectiveCtrl via $scope
    $scope.parentDirectiveCtrl();
  };
})

.directive('fooDirective', function () {
  return {
    // Passing in parentDirectiveCtrl into $scope here
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs, parentDirectiveCtrl) {
      scope.parentDirectiveCtrl = parentDirectiveCtrl;
    },
    controller: 'FooController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    bindToController: true,
    require: '^parentDirective'
  };
});
```

Here I'm just using `$scope` to pass through `parentDirectiveCtrl`, which seems a little clunky.

Is there another way to access the `require`-ed controller from the directive's controller without the linking function?

Comment: You don't have to pass it via scope - you can just assign it to your own controller...but otherwise, yes - you need a link function

Comment: How do you mean by assigning it?

Comment: You require both your own controller and a parent... `require: ["fooDirective", "^parentDirective"]`... and assign one to the other... but it would still require a link function - which is where the required controllers are injected

Comment: Ah ok, makes senses. If you want the reputation points, please post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `link` function to acquire the `require`-ed controllers, but you don't need to use the scope to pass the reference of the controller to your own. Instead, pass it directly to your own controller:

```
.directive('fooDirective', function () {
  return {

    require: ["fooDirective", "^parentDirective"],

    link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      var me     = ctrls[0],
          parent = ctrls[1];

      me.parent = parent;
    },
    controller: function(){...},
  };
});
```

Be careful, though, since the controller runs prior to link, so within the controller `this.parent` is `undefined`, until after the link function runs. If you need to know exactly when that happens, you can always use a controller function to pass the `parentDirective` controller to:

```
link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
  //...

  me.registerParent(parent);
},
controller: function(){
  this.registerParent = function(parent){
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: can this be injected in the compile section?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to avoid using `$scope` to access parent controller, but you have to use `link` function.
Angular's documentation [says](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> **Require**
>
> Require another directive and inject its controller as the fourth
>   argument to the linking function...

**Option 1**

Since `controllerAs` creates namespace in `scope` of your controller, you can access this namespace inside your `link` function and put required controller directly on controller of `childDirective` instead of using `$scope`. Then the code will look like this.

```
angular.module('app', []).
  controller('parentController', function() {
    this.doSomething = function() {
      alert('parent');
    };
  }).
  controller('childController', function() {
    this.click = function() {
      this.parentDirectiveCtrl.doSomething();
    }
  }).
  directive('parentDirective', function() {
    return {
      controller: 'parentController'
    }
  }).
  directive('childDirective', function() {
    return {
      template: '<button ng-click="controller.click()">Click me</button>',
      link: function link(scope, element, attrs, parentDirectiveCtrl) {
        scope.controller.parentDirectiveCtrl = parentDirectiveCtrl;
      },
      controller: 'childController',
      controllerAs: 'controller',
      bindToController: true,
      require: '^parentDirective'
    }
  });
```

**Plunker**:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YwakJATaeuvUV2RBDTGr?p=preview

**Option 2**

I usually don't use controllers in my directives at all and share functionality via services. If you don't need to mess with isolated scopes of parent and child directives, simply inject the same service to both of them and put all functionality to service.

```
angular.module('app', []).
  service('srv', function() {
    this.value = '';
    this.doSomething = function(source) {
      this.value = source;
    }
  }).
  directive('parentDirective', ['srv', function(srv) {
    return {
      template: '<div>' + 
                  '<span ng-click="srv.doSomething(\'parent\')">Parent {{srv.value}}</span>' +
                  '<span ng-transclude></span>' +
                '</div>',
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope) { scope.srv = srv; }
    };
  }]).
  directive('childDirective', ['srv', function(srv) {
    return {
      template: '<button ng-click="srv.doSomething(\'child\')">Click me</button>',
      link: function link(scope) { scope.srv = srv; }
    }
  }]);
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/R4zrXz2DBzyOuhugRU5U?p=preview

Comment: I gave this a try and realized that it wouldn't work when there are multiple instances of the directives because services are singletons.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! Angular lets you pass "parent" controller. You already have it as a parameter on your link function. It is the fourth parameter. I named it ctrl for simplicity. You do not need the scope.parentDirectiveCtrl=parentDirectiveCtrl line that you have.

```
.directive('fooDirective', function () {
  return {
// Passing in parentDirectiveCtrl into $scope here
link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
  // What you had here is not required.
},
controller: 'FooController',
controllerAs: 'controller',
bindToController: true,
require: '^parentDirective'};});
```

Now on your parent controller you have

```
this.doSomething=function().
```

You can access this doSomething as

```
ctrl.doSomething().
```